# onload back function jQuery i want to go back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an onload function here, and I would like it to get me back to where I was before.

```
$("body").load("history.go(-1)").hide().fadeIn(1500).delay(6000);
```

Comment: What is your overall aim? Any code after a URL change will be ignored as the current page unloads. You can only transition if the pages are loaded visas Ajax calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go back to the previous page as soon as current page loads, you can try this,

```
$(function(){
  $(window).attr('history').back();
})
```

If this is not what you want, then please elaborate/explain your question a bit.

Comment: Welcome @RonaldoCarpio. Glad to see it helped :)